# How to get a new array with new data structure on conditions from the origin array?

Tags: javascript

Assume I have an array as my origin data set;

```js
const users = [
{id: 1, name: 'userOne', age: 23, licenseNumber: '95273380'},
{id: 2, name: 'userTwo', age: 21, licenseNumber: '95273381'},
{id: 3, name: 'userThree', age: 18, licenseNumber: ''},
{id: 4, name: 'userFour', age: 2, licenseNumber: '95273382'},
{id: 5, name: 'userFive', age: 77, licenseNumber: null},
{id: 6, name: 'userSix', age: 35, licenseNumber: '95273383'},
]
```

Now I want to create a new array based on it by conditions and with a new data structure:

1. need to filter all users if `liscenNumber` is empty or null.
2. create key value pair return (~licenseNumber`as key,`name` as value)

So far, I tried the `filiter()` method but it only handles conditions; there no way I can customise a new data structure to return.

Comment: Show us the code you tried and we can go from there.

Comment: ```javascript
const newRes = users.filter((user)=>{
if (user.licenseNumber) return user
})
```

Comment: An array of objects with different keys is usually not a good idea. A better final result would be a single object whose keys are license numbers and names are values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are, you can just use `filter` to filter - then `map` to build your new array.

```js
 const users = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "userOne",
            "age": 23,
            "licenseNumber": "95273380"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "userTwo",
            "age": 21,
            "licenseNumber": "95273381"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "userThree",
            "age": 18,
            "licenseNumber": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "userFour",
            "age": 2,
            "licenseNumber": "95273382"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "userFive",
            "age": 77,
            "licenseNumber": null
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "userSix",
            "age": 35,
            "licenseNumber": "95273383"
        }
    ]
    
   const result = users.filter(x => x.licenseNumber).map(x => ({[x.licenseNumber]: x.name}));
   
   console.log(result);
```

EDIT:

If you wanted to avoid `map` and `filter` and only iterate over the array once - then just use a `for` loop, or `forEach`, etc and manually build your result array, e.g.

```
let result = [];

users.forEach(x => x.licenseNumber && result.push({
  [x.licenseNumber]: x.name
}))
```

Comment: It would be nice if you made it a stack snippet so we could execute it and see the result.

Comment: is there any way I can do this without filter then map? feels bit wired need to loop twice for this. but yes this answer is work for me!

Comment: @sillyknight02 no - because map will return a value for every element in the array - so without filtering you would have `undefined` elements. If you wanted to do it in a single loop then you could just do it all in a regular `for` loop.

Comment: @sillyknight02 added a `forEach` example to show you how to do it in a single iteration.